# Find the first three nonzero terms in each of two linearly independent solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the first three nonzero terms in each of two linearly independent solutions about the singular point of the following ODE:

$ x^2y''+3xy'+(1-x)y=0 \ $

**Answer:**

Here $ x=0 \ $ is  a regular-singular point  .

Let $ y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n \ $ be the power series solution of the ODE .

After plugging $ y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n \ $  in the given equation and simplifying , we get

$ a_0-a_0x+4a_1x+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [n(n-1)a_n+3na_n+a_n-a_{n-1} ] =0 \ $

This gives $ a_0=a_1=0 \ $

This would give $ trivial $ solution $ y=0 \ $.

But I need two independent solutions.

Am I doing somewhere wrong approach?

**Kindly help me .**

Comment: MyGlasses gave the solution. If you make $y=x z$, you end with $x^2 z''+5x z'+(4-x)z=0$ which is more clear. Sooner or later, you will learn that this is a form of Bessel differential equation (have a look at equation (3) in  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

We have
$$p_0=\lim_{x\to0}(x-0)p(x)=\lim_{x\to0}x\dfrac{3}{x}=3~~~,~~~q_0=\lim_{x\to0}(x-0)^2q(x)=\lim_{x\to0}x^2\dfrac{1-x}{x^2}=1$$
then $0$ is regular point of the equation and the characteristic equation is $r(r-1)+rp_0+q_0=0$ or $r=-1$, so your solution must be of the form 
$$y=x^r\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=x^{-1}(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots)$$